# Разделить все точки на пары с минимальным расстоянием

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, координаты

1. Есть чётное количество точек на координатной плоскости. Нужен алгоритм, как разделить **все точки** на пары с минимально возможным расстоянием у всех.

   Самый простой вариант - для каждой точки находить расстояние со всеми и выбирать минимальное. Но тогда получится, что оставшиеся в конце точки будут с максимальным расстоянием. А так не должно быть
2. Есть точки на координатной плоскости. Нужен алгоритм, как разделить все точки на пары с минимально возможным расстоянием у всех. Пары типа A-B, B-C, C-D (в любом порядке, каждая точка должна встречать в двух парах).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113342/discussion-on-question-by---------).

Comment: "Но тогда получится, что оставшиеся в конце точки будут с максимальным расстоянием. А так не должно быть" т.е. суммарное расстояние не важно, а нужно искать минимальное среднее?